# Vacation booking reference problem with checkmytrip.com

Tags: airlines, bookings, check-in, gds

I've just booked my trip at **Aeroflot** airlines via (Van Vic Vacations), I recieved a mail confirmation with the booking reference number. I've tried to use this number along my last name at **checkmytrip.com**, yet I always get the following error

> We are unable to find this reservation number. Please check your entry and try again. Please note that not all reservations can be accessed via this service. (8104 - 1929)

I've found my ticket at the **Aeroflot** site to be with the status re-confirmed along the e-ticket number.

I would like to know what causes such an error? shall I contact **Aeroflot**?

Comment: If Aeroflot site confirms that your ticket is valid, then the issue is with checkmytrip.com.  As long as the airline company confirms your tickets, you are fine.

Comment: IIRC, CheckMyTrip only works with Amadeus references. Other systems exist, such as Sabre, so if Aeroflot use anything other than Amadeus then their reference wouldn't be compatible with CheckMyTrip

Comment: Aeroflot seem to use Sabre for their online checkin (so I would assume they use it throughout!). Perhaps worth trying the reference number in Tripcase, as in CGCampbell's answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check My Trip](http://www.checkmytrip.com) is the end user portal provided by the [Amadeus](http://www.amadeus.com) [GDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Distribution_System). [Sabre](http://www.sabre.com), a competing [Global Distribution System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Distribution_System), used to run [Virtually There](http://www.virtuallythere.com), but it has been redirected to (and rebranded as) [TripCase](http://www.tripcase.com).

You'll need to contact your travel agency, Van Vic Vacations, to find out for sure which GDS they use, whether Amadeus (unlikely), Sabre, or another. They do not appear to have a web presence, so without calling them directly, I do not know which it is. As you have already confirmed your booking with [AeroFlot](http://www.aeroflot.com/cms/en) directly, however, any concerns you have about booking validity should already be allayed.

Happy Flying!

Comment: I've tried with [TripCase](http://tripcase.com) and it worked perfectly, I was even to link the trip with my email! Thanks.